# Access time field query

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with LessonName which is text, a FromTime field which is the time that the lesson starts and a ToField which is the time the lesson finish.
The student when comes to the class pass his card and the system tells him if he is in time.
The prefered time is 15 minutes before the class starts and 15 minutes after the class starts.
I want to make a query to check the current time and see if he is in the prefered time.
The table have records like Math, 11:00:00, 12:00:00 and History, 10:00:00, 11:00:00.
I cant find how to substract 15 minutes from the FromTime and Add 10 minutes to the same field.
I only find the

```
select * from lessons where time() between fromtime and totime
```

which shows result only if the student pass in the class schedule.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add and subtract intervals from dates/times, use the `DateAdd` function. To add or subtract minutes, use "n" as the interval:

```
SELECT * FROM lessons 
WHERE Time() BETWEEN DateAdd("n", -15, fromtime) AND DateAdd("n", 10, fromtime)
```